# Duplicate element search and replacement logic in HashMap

Tags: java, collections

This question was asked to me in a job interview and I still don't know answer so ask here. Lets say hashCode() of key object returns a fixed integer so HashMap would look like a LinkedList.

> How would a duplicate element be found and replaced by new value in map?

e.g. if following 1001 puts are performed in order listed below,

> put(1000,1000), put(1,1), put( 2, 2), put ( 3,3 ) ....put(999,999), put(1000,1000 )

Would map be traversed all the way to end and then new one be inserted at head when last put(1000,1000) is performed?

OR

Map has some other way to locate and replace duplicate keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First case is correct.**

In your case when `hashCode()` is returning same hash value for all the keys. In the java `HashMap`, Key and Value both are stored in the bucket as `Map.Entry` object. When perform the second or further `put()` operations into the map, it will traverse all the element to check whether Key is already present in the `Map`. If Key is not found then new Key and Value pair will be added into the linked list. If Key is found in the list then it update the Value for the pair.

Details explanation about java `HashMap` working: [How HashMap works in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/02/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html)

---

Take this sample code and run in the debug mode and observe how the new Key and Value pair are inserted into the Map.

In the class you will need to `hashCode()` (we want to control how the hash codes are generated for `Node`), `toString()` (just to output the `Node` value in SOUT) and `equals()` (defines the equality of the keys based on the value of `Node` member variable Integer, for updating the values.) methods for getting it working.

```
public class HashMapTest {

static class Node {
  Integer n;

  public Node(int n) {
    this.n = n;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return n%3;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object object) {
    Node node = (Node)object;
    return this.n.equals(node.n);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return n.toString();
  }
}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Node, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i<6; i++) {
      map.put(new Node(i), ""+i);   // <-- Debug Point
    }
    map.put(new Node(0), "xxx");
  }                                 // <-- Debug Point
}
```

First `3` entries in the map:  (hash code is n%3)

[image]

Three more values: (hash code is n%3)

[image]

Now don't confused about the ordering of the node, I have executed them on java 1.8 and `HashMap` uses `TreeNode`, an implementation of Red-Black tree as per the code documentation. **This can be different in different versions of the java.**

Now lets update the Value of Key `0`:

[image]

Comment: You say **If Key is found in the list then it update the Value for the pair** , value will be updated but will new (key , value ) pair remains at same position in list or added at beginning of list?  Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @Sabir_Khan I have added some more information and sample code for doing more experiments.

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful !!

Comment: As pointed out by @ThrowAway101 below, implementation has changed in JDK8 to address this issue , [Link](https://dzone.com/articles/hashmap-performance)

Comment: @SabirKhan This is java 1.8 and it is using `TreeNode` not the linked list. Linked list a general concept which is used to handle collision.

Answer (score 1):

When the hash code is the same, the hash map compares objects using the equals method.

For example, let's say you put a bunch of elements in the hash map:

```
put(1000,1000), put(1,1), put( 2, 2), put ( 3,3 ) ....put(999,999)
```

And then you do this:

```
put(1000,1000 )
```

1000 is already in the map, the hash code is the same, it is also the same in terms of the equals method, so the element will be replaced, no need to iterate further.

Now if you do:

```
put(1234, 1234)
```

1234 is not yet in the map. All the elements are in a linked list, due to the fixed hash code. The hash map will iterate over the elements, comparing them using equals. It will be false for all elements, the end of the list will be reached, and the entry will be appended.

Comment: Are you saying that map would know that 1000 is already exists in map without fully traversing the map( when I do put ( 1000, 1000) the second time)?

Comment: It iterates over the elements. 1000 was the first put in the map. So it will be the same when iterating. It's equal to 1000. So it can stop iterating. What's putting you off?

Comment: My understanding is that first put (1000,1000) will place (1000,1000) in the end of list since insertion happens at head. That is why I asked in my question , Would map be traversed all the way to end and then new one be inserted at head when last put(1000,1000) is performed?

Comment: so my understanding is - first (1000,1000 ) is at 1000th position in the list( after insertion of 999 more elements )  and then doing second put (1000,1000) changes its position from end to beginning. Is that correct?

Comment: I see. I think that's implementation dependent. The insertion order of hash collisions (append to end, prepend to head, other) is not a very common topic when discussing hash maps. You can look at the source code on grepcode.com

Answer (score 1):

JDK implementations changes over time !

In JDK8, if the hashCode() is a constant value, the implementation creates a tree not a linked list in order to protect against DDOS attack [1](http://www.securityweek.com/hash-table-collision-attacks-could-trigger-ddos-massive-scale).

Comment: Thanks for the linked article !!